# How to set up personal picture for every state of button in tkinter?

Tags: python, image, button, tkinter

I am creating program and want to use buttons with personal design, but as I find out tkinter can just allow you to set up one image for all states of button, is this possible to make it like in HTML and CSS?

P.S.: In result I also want to have button without deep effect when click on it

This is a main menu for my program which calculate student rating, button is used to choose category

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

w = 854
h = 480

root.title("Calculator 2.0")
root.geometry('%dx%d' % (w, h))
root.resizable(False, False)
filename=tk.PhotoImage(file='.\\Main_Menu.png')
background_label = tk.Label(root, image=filename)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

vp = tk.PhotoImage(file='.\\Buttons\\But_VP_idle.png')

but_vp = tk.Button(root, image=vp, bg='#131313', bd=0, 
activebackground='#BC51CD')

but_vp.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)

root.mainloop()
```

I expect for nice looking buttons, but the actual output is not what i expected.

Comment: *"possible to make it like in HTML and CSS?"*: Yes, you have to implemnt it by yourself.

Comment: I mentioned this like example that there are three possible positions of the button (idle/pressed/released). And change picture for each of this position.

Comment: *"(idle/pressed/released)"*: Yes, it's possible. Inherit from `Label` and extend it with `.bind(<Event>...` and change the `image=...` accordingly to the `.state`.